# Why Has My Google PageSpeed Insights Score Lowered So Much?

Tags: javascript, css, optimization, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

## Prod

For desktop, I have a site with a decent page speed score (currently, 96): https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.usstoragecenters.com%2Fstorage-units%2Fca%2Falhambra%2F2500-w-hellman-ave&tab=desktop

## Stage

I'm trying to improve the score (mostly for mobile), but I've somehow made it worse (currently, 69 on desktop): https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstage.usstoragecenters.com%2Fstorage-units%2Fca%2Falhambra%2F2500-w-hellman-ave%3Fplain%3Dtrue&tab=mobile

## Problem

While converting the site from Angular (the first link) to plain JavaScript (second link), I've managed to lower the desktop Google PageSpeed Insights score from 96 to 69.

I've massive reduced the amount of JavaScript and other resources (2MB on prod vs 500KB on stage).

## Analysis

Looking through the numbers, the thing that stands out to me is that prod has an FCP (First Contentful Paint) of 0.7 seconds, while stage has an FCP of 2.0 seconds. This seems weird to me since stage should be much faster, but is apparently much slower.

Looking at the mobile timeline of thumbnails (desktop is a bit hard to see), it appears as if stage renders the first "full content" much faster:

[image: Comparison of Stage and Prod Mobile Timelines in PageSpeed Insights]

I highlighted the ones that visually look "complete" to me (stage is on top, prod is on bottom).

## Screenshots

Here are some screenshots so you can see what I do (PageSpeed Insights differs fairly significantly each time it's run).

Here is stage:

[image: Stage Screenshot of PageSpeed Insights]

And here is production:

[image: Production Screenshot of PageSpeed Insights]

## Summary of Changes

Here are the main things I did when trying to improve the score:

- I converted the JavaScript from Angular to plain JavaScript, significantly reducing the JavaScript required to render the page.
- I lazy loaded JavaScript (e.g., Google Maps JavaScript isn't loaded until it's needed).
- I lazy loaded images (e.g., the slideshow initially only loads the first image).
- I reduced the number of DOM elements (from 4,600 to 1,700).
- I am using HTTP/2 server push to load the new plain JavaScript as fast as possible.

Those changes should have improved the score.

## Question

Do you have any ideas of why, despite my best efforts, the PageSpeed score tanked?

Comment: BTW, there are some cookies that check if it's the first page load (e.g., to inject critical path CSS). You can tack on "&simulate-first-page-load=true" as a query string parameter to any URL to see what Google would see for the first page load.

Comment: Are staging and production on equally fast, powerful servers and backend databases? Was staging's score high before your changes?

Comment: Yeah, they're virtually identical, and stage was very close to prod before. Both servers are using Cloudflare as a proxy, so there is some heaving caching involved. The backend performance should largely be irrelevant in this case given that Cloudflare is caching the HTML, CSS, JavaScript, images, and so on.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question, and never any third party site. This is also related to server configuration and, to a degree, SEO, both of which are off topic here.

Comment: Page speed is a complicated issue. If I could reduce this to a small example, I wouldn't need help finding out what the issue is. Also, the question is about PageSpeed Insights, so I must link to it. I've also included screenshots in case those links expire later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out the issue. PageSpeed Insights is drunk.

Well, it's unreliable anyway. I was able to dramatically improve the score by simply removing the server pushing of the JavaScript files (less than 20KB of them).

This is weird because the page actually seems to take longer to display. However, Google PageSpeed Insights thinks it's displaying sooner, and so it improves the score.

One time I tried, the mobile score went up to 99:

[image: Mobile PageSpeed Insights Score of 99]

I tried again and got a more reasonable 82:

[image: Mobile PageSpeed Insights Score of 82]

And on desktop, the score went up to 98:

[image: Desktop PageSpeed Insights Score of 98]

The interesting thing about the mobile screenshot showing 99 is that you can see in the timeline thumbnails that the image for the slideshow at the top of the page hasn't loaded yet. So it seems like a case of Google PSI prematurely deciding that the page has "finished loading", even though it hasn't finished.

It's almost like if you delay certain things long enough, Google will ignore them. In other words, the slower the page is, the better the score they will give you. Which is of course backwards.

In any event, this might be one of those things where I'll go with the slightly less optimal approach in order to achieve a higher score. There may also be a middle ground I can explore (e.g., have the first JavaScript file inject link rel=preload tags in order to load the rest of the JavaScript files immediately rather than wait for the full chain of modules to resolve).

If somebody can come up with a more satisfactory explanation, I'll mark that as the answer. Otherwise, I may end up marking this one as the answer.

## Middle Ground Approach

**EDIT**: Here's the middle ground approach I went with that seems to be working. First, I load a JavaScript file called `preload.js` that is included like this:

```
<script src="/preload.js" defer></script>
```

This is the content of the `preload.js` file:

```
// Optimization to preload all the JavaScript modules. We don't want to server push or preload them
// too soon, as that negatively impacts the Google PageSpeed Insights score (which is odd, but true).
// Instead, we start to load them once this file loads.
let paths = window.preloadJavaScriptPaths || [],
    body = document.querySelector('body'),
    element;
paths.forEach(path => {
    element = document.createElement('link');
    element.setAttribute('rel', 'preload');
    element.setAttribute('as', 'script');
    element.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
    element.setAttribute('href', path);
    body.appendChild(element);
});
```

The backend creates a variable on the window object called `preloadJavaScriptPaths`. It is just an array of strings (each string being a path to a JavaScript file, such as `/app.js`).

The page still loads pretty fast and the score is PSI score is still good (80 mobile, 97 desktop):

[image]

Comment: Glad to know you got it figured out.  Pagespeed insight is truly drunk.  lol.  Give me quite a headache with my site sometimes too.  I did suspect the JS push a bit, but after tried removing the "plain=true" parameter out and see that the JS is no longer pushing, the score is still low, so I unwittingly cleared it out of the suspect list.  Anyway, good finding! Cheers!

Comment: Additional theory: it's been about a year, but I thought of another factor. It's really easy to server push files uncompressed. That may have been lowering the score as well (I don't remember whether or not I was compressing the server pushed files).

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommended you to look into the different between how 3rd-party scripts are included between your `Prod` and `Staging` environment.

Most of the time when I have problem with pagespeed, it's 3rd-party script that cause the tank. YMMV, though.

Just some pointer to start, as I compared the stat between the two, I noticed that this particular Wistia script works quite differently, maybe not the the problem with the script itself, but the way it's embedded are different or something.

**On Prod**

- Wistia: Main-Thread Blocking Time: 3ms  (section: Minimize third-party usage)
- Wistia: Total CPU Time: 87 ms  (section: Javascript execution time)
- Wistia: Script Evaluation: 76 ms  (section: Javascript execution time)

**On Staging**

- Wistia: Main-Thread Blocking Time: 229 ms  (section: 
  Reduce the impact of third-party code)
- Wistia: Total CPU Time: 425 ms
- Wistia: Script Evaluation: 376 ms

Comment: I get the feeling this is not it, as I've now removed Wistia, YouTube, and Recaptcha, and the score is now 49 on mobile and 70 on desktop. Also, those both existed on prod and stage, so it doesn't account for the difference.

Answer (score 2):

### The issue you have

You have done a lot of things correctly, but your score is suffering because of `First Meaningful Paint` and `First Contentful Paint`

Looking at the load order etc. I have noticed that your main HTML file has actually increased in size by 33% from 60kb to 81.6kb.

That is your first indicator of where things are going wrong as you must load all HTML before the browser can even begin to think about rendering.

The next issue is that Lighthouse (the engine behind PSI) is showing you that you don't have render blocking content but I don't think the method is perfect in showing what is blocking render.

Your site still needs the `SVG logo` and `icomoon` files to render everything above the fold.

On the main site these are loaded early, on the staging site they are deferred and start loading much later, delaying your `first Contentful paint` etc.

There may be other things but those are a couple I found with a quick glance.

### How to fix the couple of items I mentioned

`HTML size` - maybe externalise some of the `JSON` etc. you have inlined as there is a lot there, lazy load it in instead (suggestion only, haven't explored whether feasible for you)

`SVG Logo` - simple to fix, grab the actual text that makes up the logo and inline it instead of using an external resource.

`icomoon` - not quite as easy to fix but swap all your icons for inline `SVGs`.

**Bonus** - by changing your icons from fonts to `SVG` you help with accessibility for people who have their own style sheets that override fonts (as fonts for icons get over-ridden and make no sense).

**Bonus 2** - One less request!

### How to Identify Problems

If anyone comes across problems like this you need to do the following to work out what is going on.

Open Developer Tools and go to network tab first.

Set the options to 'Disable Cache - true' and 'Slow 3G' in the dropdown box.

Load each version of the site and compare the waterfall.

Normally you can spot changes in load order and start investigating them - the 'game' is to find items that appear above the fold and try and remove them, defer them or inline them as you have with some of your CSS.

Next thing is to learn to use the Coverage and Rendering tabs as they very quickly point you to problems.

Finally learn how to use the performance tab and understand the trace it produces.

You may already know how to use the above, but if not learn them they will let you find all of your problems quickly.